# evaluate the aggregate of percentage in variable

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe and I want to calculate occurrence of percentage of text in columns.
for example in dataframe below i want to calculate percentage of freq of text in all columns.

I tried by janitor:tabyl and also Table but doesn't work.

```
df <- data.frame(CA = c("USED", "USED", "USED", "USED", "USED", "USED", "USED", "USED", "USED", "USED", NA, NA),
                 MA = c(NA, "YES",  "YES",  NA, NA, "YES",  "YES",  "YES",  "YES",  NA, NA, NA),
                 NY = c(NA, "Stock",    NA, NA, "Stock",    "Stock",    NA, "Stock",    NA, "Stock",    "Stock",    "Stock"),
                 TX = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, "Recieved", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA))
```

The output should be like

[image]

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck? Please share your attempt

Comment: I tried Table and janitor::Tabyl

Comment: Ok, share your attempt and show us why it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `summarise()` `across()` every variable.

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- df %>% 
  summarise(
    across(
      everything(),
      ~ (mean(!is.na(.)) * 100) %>% 
        round() %>% 
        paste0("%")
    )
  ) 

df1

#    CA  MA  NY TX
# 1 83% 50% 58% 8%

labels <- map_chr(df, ~ unique(.[!is.na(.)]))

df2 <- df1 %>% 
  setNames(labels)

df2

#   USED YES Stock Recieved
# 1  83% 50%   58%       8%
```

Comment: why we calculated mean here ...???  i want to canculate count of USed in column/ sum of total  row

Comment: `is.na()` returns a logical (TRUE/FALSE) that checks if the value is missing. Then, the `mean()` call converts that to integer (1 for TRUE, 0 for FALSE). Mean values here mean the proportion of values that are not missing. Then, I turned that into a percentage and add %.

Comment: I tried the same thing but now i get to know why it was not working for me, Thanks for help

Comment: If i want to label column names of summary as USED,Yes, stock recieved
for example in output summary if i want USED, YES,Stock, Recieved in place of CA, MA, NY, TX...??

Comment: I added some code to the answer. Label is a character vector created from the unique value of each column that is not missing. `setNames` changed the column names.

Comment: labels <- map_chr(dataset, ~ unique(.[!is.na(.)]))
Error: Result 4 must be a single string, not a logical vector of length 0
what can be a reason for this error..??

Comment: It looks like there is something wrong with the 4th column; I'm not sure what it might be. You may want to take a look at it's values.

Answer (score 0):

With Base R:

```
apply(!is.na(df),2,mean)

        CA         MA         NY         TX 
0.83333333 0.50000000 0.58333333 0.08333333
```

Comment: why mean here ...?

Comment: Because `T == 1` and `F == 0` so the mean gives the percentage

Answer (score 0):

We may use `colMeans` on a logical `matrix`

```
round(colMeans(!is.na(df)) * 100, 2)
   CA    MA    NY    TX 
83.33 50.00 58.33  8.33
```